# After Migartion from SP2010 to SP2013,Existing One Note files not synching

Tags: sharepoint-2013, synchronization, onenote

We have a document library in SP 2010 which has some one note files synched from 2010 One Note client.
After migration to SP 2013, the One Note files exists in 2013 document library, but they are not being synched now .Receiving the following error.
An error occurred while attempting to sync this section or notebook. (Error code: 0xE402005F)

I have made sure the path of the files is pointing to the new location. If I create a new One note file and synch it to SP2013 library, it works fine, but exisiting One Note files are not synching.
Has anyone faced this issue?